# How to Remove Text Spacing?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML/CSS so please forgive this simple question.

I need to create some large text for a heading on my web page. This is what I have done..

```
HTML
<h2>TEST HEADER</h2>

CSS
h2 {
    font-size: 80px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
}
```

When I look at the the browser there is empty space between the text and the top and bottom of the h2 container. I have not added any padding or even a margin.

The smaller the font size, the smaller the empty space. The bigger the font size, the bigger the empty space.

Why is this space there and how can I remove it please?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

This is browser default. You should use **CSS reset** like [this](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset) at the beginning of your CSS codes.